# Phonegap App + JQM keep going to main page of my App

Tags: android, ajax, jquery-mobile, phonegap, mobile-application

Stuck on this from few days,tried almost every solution.

Steps:

1) Login page - makes an AJAX call to authenticate the user.

2) Home Page -after logged IN.

3) Profile Page - User click on the Profile and that makes an AJAX call to grab data and fill the form , on FORM submit it goes to another function that sends data back to DB and at the end have :

```
" $.mobile.changePage($("#home-page"), null, true, true);
"
```

Excepting to change the page to HOME page and stick there.
But on Android it goes back to LOGIN page.
Browser works totally fine

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks